# keras: multiple w_constraints

Tags: python, constraints, keras

I want a set of weights to be constrained to have a fixed norm (as in `unitnorm`) and non-negative values (as in `nonneg`).  This pair of constraints is useful in some kinds of optical modeling.

I'm not a Python expert, so I tried `W_constraint = nonneg(), W_constraint = maxnorm(1))` and got `SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated`.  Is there a better way?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the topology.py file in the keras source code it has a property:

```
    @property
def constraints(self):
    cons = {}
    for layer in self.layers:
        for key, value in layer.constraints.items():
            if key in cons:
                raise Exception('Received multiple constraints '
                                'for one weight tensor: ' + str(key))
            cons[key] = value
    return cons
```

which raises an exception when multiple constraints are received for one weight tensor. I think the best way to do this would be to implement a custom constraint (say nonneg_and_maxnorm?), you can see examples of implemented constraints in constraints.py in the keras source code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed reply!

Comment: Also, a good place to ask keras questions is the keras-users google group. I have found that to be quite helpful. You might want to re ask your question there and someone might be able to give you a better reply than mine.